# how to structure this correctly in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

So I have a `Team` and an `Event`, with a `one-to-many` relationship and a `date` column on the `Event`. What I want to do in SQL is:

`select * from events where team_id = :team_id and date > date.now()`

How do I accomplish this using `firebase web`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's unclear whether you've made an attempt to research or solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. You'll need to create a synthetic property that combines the values you want to filter on, i.e. `"team_date": "teamA_1505273544886"`. Also see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase